# What and when does HTMLFormElement.submit() return?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

Looking at js method docs I always miss information about the return type/value and when it returns if it is async. The same problem here for `HTMLFormElement.submit()`. By now I have figured out that it is an async operation (?), but does it return anything and when does it return , immediately or after making the http post request?

The reason why I am asking is because I am not sure if calling `HTMLFormElement.reset()` directly after `HTMLFormElement.submit()` is running into problems (problems like form fields get cleared by `reset()` before `submit()` has made the post request).

Furthermore is using promises like this:

```js
Promise.resolve(function(){document.getElementById('form').submit();})
       .then(function(){document.getElementById('form').reset();});
```

of any help?

---

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I'm asking about cases where there is no redirect after the submit call. Especially (a) when the form has attr `target="_blank"` set; and (b) when the server response is not html but for example a file, a download of the file would be initiated but no redirect (I know that some websites solve this problem by first redirecting to a download site and so on but others don't do that and its much more nice in my opinion if you download a file without getting redirected to a download site).

Comment: Nothing is returned from the `submit` function nor executed after it. The location of the page is changed during `submit` execution, and all the JS and other content of the page will be cleared, and a new page will be loaded.

Comment: @Teemu indeed. Unless this form is somehow not doing that. But I'm not sure what OP means by  "problems".

Comment: @Teemu it can get executed if the form is not valid and the new page is not loaded, see the [standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-form-submit)

Comment: @Teemu But what happens if the form has `target="_blank"`? The page is not reloaded (or redirected), the form has still all values in and functions get excecuted after the submit call.

Comment: @VLAZ By problems I mean can it eventually happen that form fields get cleared before the http POST request is made.

Comment: @jonatjano Well thank you very much for the reference to the standard!!! (should have checked it before asking). As far as i see this know the request is first being fully build then queued and then submit is returning. Therefore calling reset directly after submit should be safe!

Comment: @ezegoing Only that the form is always submitted when calling form's submit method from JS, no matter if ex. required field(s) are empty, also the attached submit event is not fired. See a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5q67kxuL/).